# Error while centering table

Tags: tables

Sorry for the example being too long, but identifying what is missing so that I can centralize the table, would be of good help.

```
    \documentclass{article}
% REFERÊNCIAS------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[%
    alf,
    abnt-emphasize=bf,
    bibjustif,
    recuo=0cm,
    abnt-url-package=url,       % Utiliza o pacote url
    abnt-refinfo=yes,           % Utiliza o estilo bibliográfico abnt-refinfo
    abnt-etal-cite=3,
    abnt-etal-list=3,
    abnt-thesis-year=final
]{abntex2cite}                  % Configura as citações bibliográficas conforme a norma ABNT

% PACOTES----------------------------------------------------------------------
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                                 % Codificação do documento
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                    % Seleção de código de fonte
\usepackage{booktabs}                                       % Réguas horizontais em tabelas
\usepackage{color, colortbl}                                % Controle das cores
\usepackage{float}                                          % Necessário para tabelas/figuras em ambiente multi-colunas
\usepackage{graphicx}                                       % Inclusão de gráficos e figuras
\usepackage{icomma}                                         % Uso de vírgulas em expressões matemáticas
\usepackage{indentfirst}                                    % Indenta o primeiro parágrafo de cada seção
\usepackage{microtype}                                      % Melhora a justificação do documento
\usepackage{multirow, array}                                % Permite tabelas com múltiplas linhas e colunas
\usepackage{subeqnarray}                                    % Permite subnumeração de equações
\usepackage{lastpage}                                       % Para encontrar última página do documento
\usepackage{verbatim}                                       % Permite apresentar texto tal como escrito no documento, ainda que sejam comandos Latex
\usepackage{amsfonts, amssymb, amsmath}                     % Fontes e símbolos matemáticos
\usepackage[algoruled, portuguese]{algorithm2e}             % Permite escrever algoritmos em português
%\usepackage[scaled]{helvet}                                % Usa a fonte Helvetica
\usepackage{times}                                          % Usa a fonte Times
%\usepackage{palatino}                                      % Usa a fonte Palatino
%\usepackage{lmodern}                                       % Usa a fonte Latin Modern
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}                               % Mantém as notas de rodapé sempre na mesma posição
\usepackage{ae, aecompl}                                    % Fontes de alta qualidade
\usepackage{latexsym}                                       % Símbolos matemáticos
\usepackage{lscape}                                         % Permite páginas em modo "paisagem"
%\usepackage{picinpar}                                      % Dispor imagens em parágrafos
%\usepackage{scalefnt}                                      % Permite redimensionar tamanho da fonte
%\usepackage{subfig}                                        % Posicionamento de figuras
%\usepackage{upgreek}                                       % Fonte letras gregas
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{caption,multicol,booktabs,array}
% Redefine a fonte para uma fonte similar a Arial (fonte Helvetica)
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}

\title{tabela}
\author{matheusmachadoufsc }
\date{May 2017}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section{Introduction}
% Please add the following required packages to your document preamble:
    % \usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
    % If you use beamer only pass "xcolor=table" option, i.e. \documentclass[xcolor=table]{beamer}
    \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \caption{My caption}
    \label{my-label}
    \vspace{0.5cm}
    {\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
    \begin{tabular}{llllll}
    \rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
    \textbf{Aplicação}                                                                               & \textbf{O que é}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    & \textbf{Como}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & \textbf{Onde}                                                                                                                           & \textbf{Pra quem}                                                                                                                                            & \textbf{Objetivo}                                                                                                                                                                                                                      \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{}}                                           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Cartazes com etiqueta NFC embutidas, com informações armazenadas.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Espalhando os cartazes com a etiqueta, em diversos lugares da biblioteca. Os usuários necessitam apenas possuir um celular com NFC, e aproximar do cartaz, dessa forma, consegue realizar o download do livro.}                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Biblioteca virtual\\ Na\\ Áustria\end{tabular}}                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Usuários que preferem ter o livro em seus Smartphone e/ou quando o livro não está disponível}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Realizar downloads de  livros}                                                                                                                                                             \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Smart Posters}}                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Projeto com fim Educativo, que auxiliar jovens em obter conhecimentos sobre a sua região.}                                                                                                                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Foram espalhados pela cidade etiquetas NFC que contêm informações referente ao pontos que foi inserida. Com a aproximação do dispositivo móvel, consegue ler a etiqueta e receber as informações na tela do celular.}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Finlândia\\ em Oulu\end{tabular}}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Sociedade}                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Ajudar jovens a obter informações \\ sobre rotina, habilidades e conhecimentos histórico/cultural sobre a sua região e desenvolver gestão de vida\end{tabular}} \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Um folheto de supermercado, onde cada produto está inserido uma etiqueta NFC.}                                                                                                                                                                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Etiquetas embutidas no folheto, através do aplicativo lê-se as etiquetas apenas aproximando o dispositivo ao produto desejado e os pedidos são enviados para um sistema,do supermercado, na qual realiza a entrega das compras no mesmo dia.}                            & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Finlândia\\ em Oulu\end{tabular}}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Usuários que\\ frequentam\\ Supermercados\end{tabular}}                               & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Realizar compras utilizando o dispositivo móvel que possui NFC sem sair do imóvel.}                                                                                                        \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B6B1B1}}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Sistema de pagamentos da Google que permite ao usuário utilizar seu dispositivo móvel que contenha a tecnologia NFC como um cartão de crédito. Ao invés de carregar diversos\\ cartões o sistema permite ativar os cartões em seu dispositivo.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Apenas aproximando seu smartphone do leitor NFC instalado nas máquinas de cartões ou de um terminal.}                                                                                                                                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Google Wallet}                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Para pessoas que querem praticidade\\ na hora de realizar pagamentos.\end{tabular}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Realizar transações através do smartphone.}                                                                                                                                                \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B6B1B1}\textbf{Pagamento}}                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Pulseiras de pagamentos que possuem a Tecnologia NFC integrada.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                        & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}A pulseira funciona como um cartão pré-pago, assim, o usuário carrega a pulseira com uma quantidade de saldo via cartão de débito e aproxima da plataforma de pagamento.}                                                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Empresa\\ Valid\end{tabular}}                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Para pessoas que querem praticidade\\ na hora de realizar pagamentos.\end{tabular}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Realizar pagamentos utilizando a pulseira.}                                                                                                                                                \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B6B1B1}}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Sistema de pagamento usando o dispositivo móvel.}                                                                                                                                                                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Para utilizar necessita possuir o dispositivo com NFC, instalar o aplicativo, cadastrar o cartão e reconhecer a impressão digital.}                                                                                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Samsung\\ Pay\end{tabular}}                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Para pessoas que querem praticidade na\\ hora de realizar\\ pagamentos.\end{tabular}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Realizar pagamentos utilizando o smartphone.}                                                                                                                                              \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Jogos}}                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Cartão que possui a tecnologia NFC acoplada para desbloqueio ou visualizar informações na tela\\ dispositivo.\end{tabular}}                                                                                                                                  & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Aproximando o cartão que é disponibilizado pela empresa ao celular com NFC.}                                                                                                                                                                                             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Nokia}                                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}\begin{tabular}[c]{@{}l@{}}Usuários de dispositivos da\\ Nokia que possuem os jogos instalados.\end{tabular}}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Desbloquear níveis de jogos.}                                                                                                                                                              \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Pulseiras com a tecnologia NFC integrada para iniciar jogos eletrônicos, capturar fotos e vídeos do usuário.}                                                                                                                                                                           & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}A pulseira possui identificação única e é codificada. No parque estão espalhados 25 leitores,  para a criança jogar necessita aproximar a pulseira do leitor NFC que coleta as informações contida na pulseira e encaminha para o sistema do parque.}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Mongo Park em Israel}                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Para crianças}                                                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Entreter as crianças enquanto os pais realizam suas compras, com diversos jogos}                                                                                                           \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B6B1B1}\textbf{Alimentador Inteligente}}                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Alimentador para animais de estimação, na qual fornece ração com a quantidade determinada e,monitora a quantidade de água ingerida avisando o dono sobre essa ação.}                                                                                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}O equipamento possui duasantenas RFID, implantadas uma no bebedouro e outra no comedouro, através das antenasconsegue a comunicação com a tag NFC que deve está pendurada no pescoço do animal, assim, o alimentador Consegue funcionar.}                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Colégio SESI deCianorte no Paraná}                                                          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Para pessoas que possuem algum animal de estimação.}                                                             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Facilitar a vida de pessoas que possuem algum animal de estimação, gerando menores preocupações sobre a saúde do animal.}                                                                  \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Aluguel de Bicicletas}}                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Sistema de aluguel para bicicletas em terminais distribuídos pela cidade.}                                                                                                                                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Deverá possuir um smartphone que contenha a tecnologia NFC e o aplicativo disponibilizado pela empresa, assim, os ciclistas podem efetuar login no sistema pelo dispositivo, inserindo o PIN em uma estação e se o cliente for autorizado é Liberado o uso da bicicleta} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Nextbike, empresa que oferece serviços para aluguel de bicicletas em Leipzig, na Alemanha.} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Usuários de bicicletas Alugadas.}                                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Realizar a identificação Das bicicletas e usuários.}                                                                                                                                       \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B6B1B1}{\color[HTML]{000000} \textbf{Garrafas conectadas}}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Garrafas que possui NFC acoplado para fornecer informações do produto ao consumidor.}                                                                                                                                                                                                   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Colocando etiqueta NFC nas garrafas, assim, o consumidor consegue aproximar o smartphone da garrafa e obter informações sobre o produto.}                                                                                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Tesco no ReinoUnido, pela marcaMalibu.}                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Consumidores de bebidas alcoólica.}                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Realizar a interação de Produto e consumidor.}                                                                                                                                             \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{B6B1B1}}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Garrafa de conhaque que possui na sua tampa a etiqueta NFC, para monitoramento da abertura da garrafas.}                                                                                                                                                                                & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Uma tag NFC, inserida no frasco, consegue detectar a abertura da garrafa e enviar uma mensagem de áudio que é recebida pelo servidor da empresa avisando sobre a ação .}                                                                                                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}China}                                                                                      & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Consumidores de conhaque.}                                                                                       & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{E6E5E5}Combater a falsificação da bebida na China e melhorar o relacionamento Com os clientes}                                                                                                    \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} 
    \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}\textbf{Gerenciamento de inspeções}}                 & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Etiquetas que colaboram para verificar as condições de equipamentos de segurança e os serviços prestados  em seus nos equipamentos.}                                                                                                                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Inserindo tags NFC nos equipamentos de segurança, e através de um aplicativo consegue-se verificar as informações obtidas.}                                                                                                                                              & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Canadá}                                                                                     & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Pessoas e/ou empresas que necessitam monitorar equipamentos.}                                                    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF}Monitorar equipamentos de Segurança.}                                                                                                                                                      \\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    }
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: May it be that the table is just too wide for the page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Centering (which your table already is) is by far your smallest problem. Your table is much too wide for your page, namely `3016.77289 pt` too wide. As a comparison, the available `\textwidth` in your document is `345.0 pt`, so you would need nearly 10 pages besides each other to display your table.

This is very much like trying to fit an elephant into a suitcase, but maybe with multiline cells and landscape orientation:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{
%color, 
colortbl}                    
\usepackage{multirow, array}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{caption,multicol,booktabs,array}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
  \centering
  \caption{My caption}
  \label{my-label}
  \renewcommand\arraystretch{1.25}
  \begin{tabular}{lp{3.5cm}p{4.5cm}p{2.2cm}p{3cm}p{2cm}}
    \rowcolor[HTML]{9B9B9B} 
    \textbf{Aplicação} & \textbf{O que é} & \textbf{Como} & \textbf{Onde} & \textbf{Pra quem} & \textbf{Objetivo} \\ \cline{2-6} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{EFEFEF} \cellcolor[HTML]{C0C0C0}  & Cartazes com etiqueta NFC embutidas, com informações armazenadas. & Espalhando os cartazes com a etiqueta, em diversos lugares da biblioteca. Os usuários necessitam apenas possuir um celular com NFC, e aproximar do cartaz, dessa forma, consegue realizar o download do livro. & Biblioteca virtual Na Áustria & Usuários que preferem ter o livro em seus Smartphone e/ou quando o livro não está disponível & Realizar downloads de  livros \\ \cline{2-6} 
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*(I did only the first row, as removing all these `\multicolumn{1}{l|}{...}` is tedious - what is their purpose anyway?)*

---

But ultimately it might be better to restructure the table. Maybe the first columns could be used as some kind of subsection heading and the table be split into multiple small tables?

Also the table might be easier to read without all the different shades of gray. Maybe have a look at https://www.inf.ethz.ch/personal/markusp/teaching/guides/guide-tables.pdf

---

off-topic:

- please don't load the same package multiple time, for example `booktabs` and `indentfirst` are loaded two times
- if you load `xcolor` you don't need `color`
- in your original code a floating specifier (e.g. `[htbp]`) is missing. You even get a warning about that.